# unable to click file upload in webdriver

Tags: webdriver

Could anyone please check [this](http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/) html page . I can't click the "Browse" button here .
I tried the following :-

```
//1st approach
>driver.switchTo().frame(0)
>driver.findElement(By.id("File1")).click

//2nd Approach
>(new Actions).moveToElement(..).sendKeys("Keys.ENTER") // with this i could 

//3rd by executing JS in webdriver
>document.findElementById('').value = 'C://.. ' ;
```

Nothing seems to work . Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@src,'/convert-pdf/default.aspx')]")));
driver.findElement(By.id("File1")).sendKeys("C:\\testFile.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `driver.findElement(By.id("File1")).click` has **`()`** missing at the end.
2. The page has errors that might result in you not being able to access the `iframe`:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://bcldoc2pdflb-1026005913.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/convert-pdf/default.aspx
>   from frame with URL
>   http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/default-b.aspx?utm_expid=127285-27&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14031004%2Funable-to-click-file-upload-in-webdriver.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I've tried manually (through JavaScript Console in browser's dev tools) to get the element, but couldn't get to the iframe:

```
f = document.evaluate("//*[contains(@src,'/convert-pdf/default.aspx')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
XPathResult
ifr = f.iterateNext()
<iframe src=​"http:​/​/​bcldoc2pdflb-1026005913.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/​convert-pdf/​default.aspx" width=​"460px" height=​"670px" frameborder=​"0">​…​</iframe>​
ifr.contentDocument
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://bcldoc2pdflb-1026005913.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/convert-pdf/default.aspx from frame with URL http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/default-b.aspx?utm_expid=127285-27&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14031004%2Funable-to-click-file-upload-in-webdriver. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
null
d = ifr.contentWindow.document
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://bcldoc2pdflb-1026005913.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/convert-pdf/default.aspx from frame with URL http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/default-b.aspx?utm_expid=127285-27&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14031004%2Funable-to-click-file-upload-in-webdriver. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.But I could access other elements (output text field and email field) which too are in the same IFrame. How was that possible then?

Comment: @RohitP, Have you tried what Santoshsarma has suggested? I've tried it and it worked for me (in Python, but that should not matter)

Answer (score 0):

The frame is not identified in IDE. the possible way is to do it with "AutoIT". i tried and it worked out. Here is the sample code for autoit

`Send("{ENTER}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("D:\questiontovetri.txt")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{TAB}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{TAB}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{ENTER}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{TAB}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{TAB}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{TAB}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{TAB}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{ENTER}")
    Sleep(1000)`

To use autoIT you need to download it. refer "http://veera-myseleniumblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/handling-authentication-dialog-box.html" for assistance

once you have converted you autoIT script you can call the exe in java code like

`driver.get("http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Upload a File to Convert...')]")).click();
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pp=run.exec("D:\\blog.exe");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Download PDF file')]")).click();`

this is working and i have tested it